# Compiler error on generic extension method

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I am trying to write a generic extension method that the compiler can't resolve at runtime, although visual studio's intellisense does find it.

The compiler error is `'SampleSolution.OtherGenericClass<SampleSolution.IGenericInterface<SampleSolution.ISimpleInterface>,SampleSolution.ISimpleInterface>' does not contain a definition for 'GenericExtensionMethod' and no extension method 'GenericExtensionMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'SampleSolution.OtherGenericClass<SampleSolution.IGenericInterface<SampleSolution.ISimpleInterface>,SampleSolution.ISimpleInterface>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Here is some sample code in the simplest form I could come up with that reproduces the problem. I know I could add `GenericExtensionMethod` in `IOtherGenericInterface`, but I need an extension method because it needs to be outside of `IOtherGenericInterface` implementations.

```
public interface ISimpleInterface
{

}

public interface IGenericInterface<T>
{

}

public class GenericClass<T> : IGenericInterface<T>
{

}

public interface IOtherGenericInterface<TGenericDerived>
{

}

public class OtherGenericClass<TGenericInterface, TSimpleInterface> : 
    IOtherGenericInterface<TGenericInterface>
    where TGenericInterface : IGenericInterface<TSimpleInterface>
{

}

public static class GenericExtensionMethods
{
    public static IOtherGenericInterface<TGenericInterface> 
        GenericExtensionMethod<TGenericInterface, TSimple>(
            this IOtherGenericInterface<TGenericInterface> expect)
        where TGenericInterface : IGenericInterface<TSimple>
    {
        return expect;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var exp = new OtherGenericClass<IGenericInterface<ISimpleInterface>,
                                        ISimpleInterface>();

        //exp.GenericExtensionMethod(); // This doesn't compile
    }
}
```

Comment: How about the actual compiler error? "This doesn't compile" isn't helpful...

Comment: A good way to find problems with extension methods is to call them using non-extension-method-syntax. What happens when you try that?

Comment: Good point @DanielHilgarth, I just added the actual error.

Comment: To illustrate @dtb's point: the compiler error using non-extension syntax is: `The type arguments for method 'GenericExtensionMethods.GenericExtensionMethod<TGenericInterface,TSimple>(IOtherGenericInterface<TGenericInterface>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.` - which makes it very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have enough information to unambiguously resolve the generic type parameters; you will have to use:

```
exp.GenericExtensionMethod<IGenericInterface<ISimpleInterface>, ISimpleInterface>();
```

In particular, note that the `where` constraints are validated *after* resolution - they do not participate in resolution itself - so during resolution all it can infer is the `TGenericInterface`.

Comment: I'm building a fluent API so I'm trying to leverage type inference, on most cases it has worked for me, just not for this particular case.